# How long does Lazy Mushroom last?

Tags: tap-my-katamari

There is a Lazy Mushroom for ten candies in the store. Its description is "Automatic 11x Prince/sec". Is this a limited time use? Or a timer? Or is it 11x Prince/sec automatically (without tapping) forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purchasing the "Lazy Mushroom" gives The Prince an automatic 11x tap for **one minute**.

As you can see below, while I did not manage to get a screen shot until half-way through, the timer appears over the button you originally press to purchase the mushroom.

[image: Automatic rolling using the "Lazy Mushroom" with 34 seconds left on the timer.]